# Un solo botón para acciones distintas en html y php

Tags: php, html

**Tengo un formulario el cual tiene varias opciones ¿mi problema es que necesito que al presionar sobre un item me lleve a paginas diferentes y no se como hacerlo alguien por favor me puede ayudar **

```html
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
    <option value="AB">Albacete</option>
    <option value="AL">Almería</option>
    <option value="AR">Araba</option>
    <option value="AV">Ávila</option>
    <option value="BA">Badajoz</option>
<input type="submit" name="ir al formulario" id="action" action="solicitud.php"  class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
</select>
```

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Sobre qué item se debe presionar y a qué página debe dirigir según qué criterio? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes?

Comment: Gracias ya lo he probado y funciona

Answer (score -1):

Podrias utilizar jquery si deseas incluir scripts, con el fin de que capture el elemento que ha sido seleccionado de tu select y de acuerdo a la opcion puedas establecer que te redireccione a distintas paginas o crear tu logica.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>selected demo</title>
        <style>
            div {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
            <option>Flowers</option>
            <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
            <option>Trees</option>
            <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
            <option>Grass</option>
            <option>Dirt</option>
        </select>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("select").change(function() {
            let str = "";
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                //Aqui describirias tu logica, si deseas puedes utilizar condicionales.
            });
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver mas informacion en la pagina oficial: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/